# undeclared identifier in using Eigen with visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, eigen, undeclared-identifier

I am trying to use Eigen with visual studio and when I include the file

```
  #include <unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor>
```

Following error occurs

```
  Error 4   error C2065: 'Derived' : undeclared identifier  c:\libs\ville-k-eigen-cdf3d4834d6d\unsupported\eigen\cxx11\src\tensor
  \tensorforwarddeclarations.h  19  1   EigenCLSTM
```

No idea why is it so.
Searched as well, there are no helpful posts.
Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I have read so far, it could one the internal MSVC bug.
perhaps, it helps for understanding.

Thanks